# Should I Call RaiseCanExecuteChanged in Prism' DelegateCommand?

Tags: prism, prism-4

I have written a CanExecute method for the DelegateCommand. CanExecute is not being re-evaluated as other commands which inherites from a CommandBase, that looks like this.

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);
}
```

Can I make the Prism DelegateCommand work like this, so CanExecute is automatically re-evaluated when appropriate or should I manually call RaiseCanExecuteChanged() when needed?

Answer (score 1):

How should the command or the command manager know that it's execution state changed? To have them know about that you need to signal this via the RaiseCanExecuteChanged method.

Comment: Yes how should the command manager know? I don't know, but using the command base I don't have to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged

Comment: Because you are using the Prism DelegateCommand. The DelegateCommand class is derived from DelegateCommandBase and not from CommandBase. I guess that the CommandManager itself doesn't call CanExecute on any other class but CommandBase.